# What is the process responsible for panels in RHEL7?

Tags: process, redhat-enterprise-linux, gnome3

I have RHEL7 with Gnome 3 and I need a process that is responsible for the top panel with "Applications", "Places", etc. menus on it. There is no such process as gnome-panel or anything similar to unity-panel-service for Ubuntu. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `xwininfo -wm` (and clicking on the top bar) the associated process is `/usr/bin/compiz` with the window title `unity-panel`.

Note: I'm using Ubuntu 16.10.  However, `xwininfo` should still identify any window.

Comment: Thanks for response. Unfortunately it didn't help, the output said that window id is: 0x40 (has no name) and Process id: (unknown).